# Accessing the path to the test case in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Is it possible to evaluate the path to the current test case in Selenium IDE? File uploads require a full path, and hard coding one breaks portability.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @gius I don't think I did. I ended up having the base path in a variable, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

A good workaround would be to add a test file to the project's resources directory. Every member of the team would have access to the file.

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.locator("yourButton"));
String filePath = YourClass.class.getResource("/" + fileName).getPath();
fileInput.sendKeys(filePath);
```

I have found that putting the above code block in a helper method that can be accessed by all test classes works best.